# copy section of text file - python

Tags: python-3.x, text, copy

From a previous post (see below): How could I modify this to copy out multiple sections of a text file each beginning and ending with "start and "end" strings? This code only will find one instance of "start" and "end" if not mistaken (per a previous post).

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Start":
        outfile.write(line) # add this
        copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "End":
        outfile.write(line) # add this
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I don't see that it will only run once

Comment: Please offer more clarification.

Comment: It will keep running with the for loop, and write as many as there are. Could you provide a link to the previous post.